# Is it possible to customize colour themes in Spyder to look like VS Code default theme?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, spyder

I've used VS Code for more than a year, but I switched for Spyder recently. I got really used to the colour theme in VS Code. Most importantly, it **differentiates plane text and symbol**. You can also a different colour for "np", "plt" etc. I didn't see any similar setting in Spyder colour theme management. It hurts the code readability quite a lot in my opinion, and I really can't get used to it.

Is there a way to add the VS Code theme to Spyder or modify one of the Spyder themes to implement that? I'm a newb in this programming world, I have no idea on how to do any of that.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks a lot! <3

[image]
Monokai theme in Spyder
[image]
Default theme in VS Code

Comment: The current options to customize the color scheme are in `Preferences > Appearance > Syntax highlighting theme > Edit selected scheme`. However, for the moment, there is no way to give a specific color to symbols (as far as I know). An issue that could be related to this: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1500

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other thread!

Comment: As for the Editing of the current theme, I messed with it, but there's plenty I'd like to do that I can't :/